# Approximating curved spacetime with a grid of cartesian metric tensors?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, discrete

Let's assume a universe with only some ($n$) single point masses $m_i$ in it. The point masses have initial positions in space-time, $x_{i0}$.
The spacetime between them is curved due to general relativity. (n-body-problem)

The curvature of the spacetime between those single point masses must be a solution of Einstein's field equations.
However, they are difficult to solve and there aren't solutions for the n-body-problem yet (to the best of my knowledge).

The curvature of spacetime is fully described by the metric tensor. (Or did I get something wrong here?) To derive the metric tensor, Einstein's field equations would have to be solved.

I'm wondering whether it is possible to *approximate* the true, curved, metric tensor at every point using different cartesian metric tensors.
That would be the same principle as doing infinitesimal small steps when calculating the derivative of a function f(x).
It's like using the flat tangent space-time at every point to describe the curved space-time.

Does this work? Has it been done somewhere in the literature? Are there circumstances for which this approximation doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is the basic idea behind [Regge calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regge_calculus). In Regge calculus, spacetime is approximated by a triangulation of (flat) simplices. All curvature is pushed to live on the codimension-2 edges (2-faces) between the simplices. The curvature on each 2-face can be described by the holonomy of closed curves around the 2-face. The Einstein equation reduces to conditions on the holonomies of the 2-faces meeting at each 1-face.

Any solution to the Einstein equation can be approximated in this way.

Comment: Is it possible to use cubes as well?

Comment: I would like to use cubes (4D cubes) instead: A cartesian grid. For simplicity. Could that be possible as well?

Comment: @MartyMcFly If you mean literal cubes (all sides, and faces the same size, and parallel), then I doubt that would be possible. If you just mean using rectangular grids, then that is what some numerical relativity codes are doing, e.g. the Einstein Toolkit (https://einsteintoolkit.org)

Comment: Helpful link, thank you! Why you doubt that would be possible with literal cubes? If I force the grid having all the same length, in my opinion the result is just: less precision in some direction. (??) Another question is regarding time: I would time just give the inverse of the volume of the cubes. Is that right as an approximation??